# How to resolve a remote computer name to get its IP address in Java?

Tags: java, dns, network-programming, jndi

I'm trying to come up with a program that send packets from  computer **A** to computer **B**. Both computers must have a copy of my Java program. This  require one to enter the name of the  remote computer **B** in a `JTextField` object, enter the message in a `JTextArea` object and then click the button send.

My program should be able to resolve the given computer name to IP address so to include the IP address as a parameter in my `DatagramPacket` constuctor.

I have tried using the below method to do the resolving, but I get a `javax.naming.CommunicationException`:

```
String clientname = "user";
Hashtable<String,Object> env = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "dns://www.google.com");
DirContext con = new InitialDirContext(env);
Object obj = con.lookup("clientname");
```

##### Exception thrown:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: DNS error [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]; remaining name 'user'
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:300)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Resolver.java:81)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_lookup(DnsContext.java:286)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentContext.p_lookup(ComponentContext.java:544)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:177)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeContext.lookup(PartialCompositeContext.java:166)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:121)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:145)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:786)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(DnsClient.java:411)
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(DnsClient.java:203)
... 7 more
```

### Question

How can I achieve my goal, because it seems to me like Java DNS service provider can only resolve *domain names* and not individual computer names?

I've been struggling with this for 3 days.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: www.google.com is not a DNS server. it's a **WEB** server. if you want to use google's public dns, then the ip is 8.8.8.8

Comment: @MarcB  i have replaced www.google.com with 8.8.8.8 but i get the following exception:   **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name 'user'**                                 even when i replace computer name **user** with another computer name.

Comment: then perhaps `google-public-dns-a.google.com`, which is the reverse mapping of 8.8.8.8

Comment: @MarcB  same same error. it seems like the statement cant find **google-public-dns-a.google.com**. have any other alternative bro?

Comment: @MarcB i have changed to onther google dns which is **8.4.4.4** but i get another error **javax.naming.CommunicationException: DNS error [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]; remaining name 'user**

Comment: `receive timeout`. check that your system can receive DNS traffic.

Comment: @MarcB still not working even after changing `com.sun.jndi.dns.timeout.initial` and `com.sun.jndi.dns.timeout.retries`. when i resolve a website, am getting the web server IP address. but when i try to resolve my colleague computer name who is also running on our intranet which is using 8.8.8.8 as DNS, that the time am getting the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `JNDI` is only useful if you need specific DNS attributes/entries.

Maybe the following is more suitable for you:

```
final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("clientname");
final String ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress();
```

The local DNS infrastructure - like the OS it does - will be use and you don't need to provide an DNS server by yourself.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29

> Determines the IP address of a host, given the host's name.
>
> The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address. If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.
>
> For host specified in literal IPv6 address, either the form defined in RFC 2732 or the literal IPv6 address format defined in RFC 2373 is accepted. IPv6 scoped addresses are also supported.

Comment: **That what i was looking for !**  i thought `inetAddress.getHostAddress()` can only retrive IP address of the local machine men.  problem solved. mission 101 accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-dns.html ?

It seams like:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url",    "dns://google-public-dns-a.google.com");

DirContext ictx = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes attrs1 = ictx.getAttributes("clientname", new String[] {"A"});
```

is what you want.

The timeout values are configurable either:

> env.put("com.sun.jndi.dns.timeout.initial", "2000");
>
> env.put("com.sun.jndi.dns.timeout.retries", "3");

Use FQDN (full qualified domain name) if you will use a public DNS server instead of `clientname` like shown in your Exception. Google doesn't hopefully know anything about `clientname` ;-).

Comment: The only thing i get is IP address of domains. e.g **www.yahoo.com**. **BUT** what i want is IP address of my friend's computer which is running on a LAN. not the IP address of a certain webserver. thats what i've been trying barthel.

Comment: Do you use a DNS server in your LAN or are the IP addresses 'hardcoded'? The error message in your question show me, that you would like ask Google for the IP of the host `clientname`. Use your internal DNS server instead if any.

Comment: our internal DNS server IP address is **8.8.8.8** which is the same as **google-public-dns-a.google.com**. when i resolve yahoo.com, am getting it IP address but when i resolve my collegue laptop am getting the error ! e.g resolving computer name  **mycomp-PC**.

Comment: **8.8.8.8** is the DNS server of **Google**. But `mycomp-PC` isn't registered in Googles DNS. You have to provide your own DNS or use the DNS provided by your internet service provider.

Comment: I've tried using my ISP DNS but all in vain. i think setting my own DNS seems to be the last option. but before that, do you think a router can be playing a part in this exception? since we do have a router and what i know, it can prevent a direct connection from a  computer(DNS server)  on a WAN to  a computer on a LAN. you know, something of that sort.

Comment: Do you use DHCP provided by your router (dsl/cable modem)? The most dsl/cable modem with router are providing a DNS server instead. Often it is configured as the standard network gateway on your computer. But if you don't know what I'm talking about, please give my other answer a try.

Comment: i know what you are talking about. but all have failed even after providing that DHCP IP address (which is router's IP). but your other answer worked. don't know why i couldn't think that for the last 5 days!